# "Vite Legacy" or "Babel" not resolve 'invalid regular expression flag s' compiling with vite

Tags: vuejs3, vite, transpiler

I need my application in VUE3 + Vite to work on an old version of FF (v68) and after trying different Vite plugins and with the default Targets, the application still returns the error 'invalid regular expression flag s' on Firefox68.

My current configuration in vite.config.js is this:

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue()
    ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  },
  base: '/calculadora/',
  build:{
    target: ['es2016'],
  }
})
```

Is there something I'm missing? I'm not sure if I need some kind of configuration that I'm not aware of, since I don't usually work with transpilers.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is due to browser compatibility issues,try like:

```
yarn add terser @vitejs/plugin-legacy -D
```

And in your vite.config.ts should be like :

```
import legacy from '@vitejs/plugin-legacy';

export default defineConfig({
...,
plugins:[
...,
 legacy({
            targets: [
                'firefox >= 60',
                'safari >= 10.1',
                'edge >= 79',
                'chrome > 30',
            ],
            additionalLegacyPolyfills: ['regenerator-runtime/runtime'],
            renderLegacyChunks: true,})
]
})
```

hope it helped.

Comment: The project is paused at this moment. When we work on it again i will check! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

> 'invalid regular expression flag s'

This issue is a known bug in Vue and has been resolved, see [the release notes for version 3.3.3](https://github.com/vuejs/core/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#333-2023-05-18).

To support legacy browsers while using Vite, as mentioned by Uneven, you will need to install terser and @vitejs/plugin-legacy, and put legacy() into the plugins list in the Vite configuration file (i.e., vite.config.ts), see Vite [plugin-legacy](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/tree/main/packages/plugin-legacy).